# Rails console with inexplicable error on production on fetching a record from a specific model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I have been facing this strange issue on production in Rails console: `rails c -e production`, where trying to fetch the user: `User.first` results in the following error:

```
2.7.2 :005 > User.first
Traceback (most recent call last):
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))
```

Nothing can be figured out from this error. For some reason, it happens **only with this user model**, for rest of the models, everything is working fine.

**Also, this error does not appear locally either in development or production mode.**

Attaching the user model here, for reference:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :registerable,
         :recoverable,
         :rememberable,
         :trackable,
         :confirmable,
         :omniauthable,
         :validatable

 ....
end
```

Any pointers to solving this issue will be highly appreciated.

**Update**

On further investigation and some help from chatGPT, I figured that the devise' `database_authenticable` method in the cause of the error. On removing it, everything is working fine.

Now I need to figure out why that method is throwing the error.

Comment: Any special data within the first user?

Comment: Do you have a more detailed trace of the error by any chance? From experience it looks like some code somewhere is overriding User#first. Do you open your User class somewhere in your codebase?

Comment: @zaphodbln_ It doesn't work even with find_by nor with other than first user.

Comment: @VincentRolea It doesn't work even with find_by nor with other than first user. Also, I'm unable to get any trace apart from the error mentioned in the question. Even trying to catch the exception is not returning anything useful.

Comment: You could try to change the config so that the output is more verbose - perhaps you can config.consider_all_requests_local, = true. And perhaps you can try to catch the error and output error.backtrace

Comment: No change in the output.
```2.7.2 :002 > u = User.find_by(id: 7)

Traceback (most recent call last):

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))

2.7.2 :003 > begin

2.7.2 :004 >   user = User.first

2.7.2 :005 > rescue => e

2.7.2 :006 >   Rails.logger.error "Error occurred: #{e.message}"

2.7.2 :007 >   Rails.logger.error e.backtrace.join("\n")

2.7.2 :008 > end

Traceback (most recent call last):

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))
```

Comment: There are a large number of validations and associations - I'd start by commenting them out and seeing if the issue persists.  If it does, there's something else in your code base causing the issue. If that clears the issue, start adding back in the validations and associations until you find which one is causing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright so the issue was that `database_authenticable` module has a method named `password_digest` which accepts an argument and hashes the password using bcrypt.

Now, I had an existing `password_digest` column in the database which was required by ActiveRecords's `has_secure_password` that I was using earlier.
So that method was being called without arguments and hence throwing the error: `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))`.

I had a migration to remove the `password_digest` column but apparently it failed at some point of time and I had to remove the column to make things work.

I hope it helps anyone facing a similar issue.

Comment: Happy you were able to troubleshoot this! It was a hairy one!

Comment: Indeed it was! I wouldn't have been able to figure it out without the community's help. Thanks to everyone involved.